# Hide/Show form in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm new to html and im trying to hide/show forms if the user ticks a box a form appears below it.

I have a form e.g.

```
Name : 
Username : 
Add More Users: (tickbox)
```

If the user ticks the 'Add More Users', another form with the fields 'Name,Username,Add More Users' appears below it. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="display(this)">Add more users</input>
<div id="yourDiv"> ...other forms... </div>
```

JavaScript

```
   function display(e){
    if (e.checked)
        document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = 'block';
    else
        document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

---

**An even better way to do this** (thanks to [What](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345078/what))

HTML

```
<input id="more" type="checkbox">Add More Users</input>
<div id="yourDiv"> ...other form... </div>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('more').onclick = function () {
        if (this.checked)
            document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = 'none';  
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the onclick be displayElement(this)? And you shouldn't use inline javascript - http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript- - use an event handler instead

Comment: Fast-forward 5 years, now everyone is using inline JS via a weird markup language on top of HTML called JSX...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use scripts for that.

First of all put the form you want to Show/Hide inside a `<div id="myForm">` tag 
and enclose it with

Then use jQuery http://www.jquery.com (download the jquery library and link it to your page and add an event at the loading of the page to run a function to check if the combo box is checked then execute:

```
("#myForm").toggle();
```

Comment: You don't need the extra div - you can add an id directly to the form element

Answer (score 0):

You can use .clone() and .append() (requires jQuery). You have give name attribute like

```
<input type="text" name="test[]" />
```